# How to move the cursor to the end of the tag in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

When I type the start of a tag, Sublime Text will auto-complete the end of the tag and position the cursor inside the tag.

`<code>|</code>`

I use `|` to represent the cursor. So when I finished the contents inside the tag, I want to move the cursor to the end of the tag like this:

`<code>blabla</code>|`

To do this, now I have to press Right button to move the cursor character by character, which is not efficient. Is there any shortcut to move the cursor to the end of the tag directly?

Comment: When using autocompletes, snippets etc. (in this case "code") tab key goes to next waypoint. Which means: press tab after writing your content.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a macro. This may be valuable if your tags cover multiple lines. Save the following as something like `move_to_end_tag.sublime-macro` in `Packages/User`.

```
[
    {
        "args":
        {
            "to": "tag"
        },
        "command": "expand_selection"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "by": "characters",
            "forward": true
        },
        "command": "move"
    }
]
```

You can then create a keybinding for the action.

```
{ 
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+alt+right"], 
    "command": "run_macro_file", 
    "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/move_to_end_tag.sublime-macro"} 
}
```

Of course, you can change the keys to whatever you like.

Comment: @Jek-fdrv If you enter `sublime.log_commands(True)` in the console, what comes up when you press the appropriate key binding?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in Sublime Text 3 rather than 2, but the End button (for me, between the delete and page down) does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found that annoying as well. Personally, taking the <kbd>End</kbd> key binding and applying it to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> works well enough for my purposes.

If that's easier for you, you can add this line to your user key bindings:

```
{ "keys": ["shift+space"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false} }
```

Using a macro as skuroda suggested is a good option as well since you end up with more control of the cursor placement.

Answer (score 0):

For curly braces and parentheses you can use Control + M.

Not sure about angle brackets in markup though.