# Sublime text tab/get out of a tag?

Tags: html, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

i recently started using sublime text 3 to type html5, and it is a great software for closing the tags when i type the beginning tag. However, after i type the content within the tags, is there an easier way to get out of the tag and move to something else? because now i have to use the right arrow or the mouse to get out of the tag. thanks

```
<p>|</p>
<p>content</p>|
```

Currently the cursor automatically places itself between the tags, but after i finish typing the content of the paragraph, how do i make it so the cursor goes fater the tags.

Comment: use the end key on your keyboard

Comment: related question here, but with answer for sublimetext2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138848/how-to-move-the-cursor-to-the-end-of-the-tag-in-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can get out from a tag and start a new line by 'ctrl + enter'. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL + RIGHT ARROW` or `CMD + RIGHT ARROW'`

works in Sublime and actually just about any text input.